# How to show image over text without text up and down

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a story paragraph, I want when a user clicks on the screen then all paragraph words should be hidden and one word should remain like a horse, kid, etc. Please see the below video link for better understanding.

Paragraph before user click.
[image: story paragraph]

When a user clicks on the screen then show Image and will remain one related word of image.

[image]

Video Link:
https://www.loom.com/share/2ff658bb47d3491e9924f35424480cd5

```css
.pic {
  position: relative;
}

.pic:before {
  content: '';

  /* center */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  /* scale */
  background-size: 200px;

  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;

  /* hide */
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 1.5s ease, opacity 1.5s ease;
}

#story_div:active .pic:before {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.pic.horse:before {
  background-image: url('stories/hourse.jpeg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-size: 300px 200px;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="story_div" class="member-detail-wrap" style="height:500px">
  <div class="sqs-block-content">
    <p id="story">

    <span class="pic horse"> A small horse came to the farm, Sam wanted to play with the </span> horse <span class='pic farm'> but the horse was scared of sam.</span>

     </p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please clearly define your question. You've outlined a task but haven't actually *asked* anything.

Comment: I understand the question now, but where is the problem and what have you tried?

Comment: Please check the video I need same to same like this

Comment: @SalmanIqbal Users shouldn't have to navigate to an external URL to understand your issue. Your question should be useful to future readers. If that link goes down, your question becomes useless. If your question relies entirely on that link, then it's off-topic. You can use the link to supplement your question, but we should be able to understand and answer without it. It's quite clear what you *want*, but not what you're *asking*.

Comment: @SalmanIqbal You will have to do this with JS, however there isn't any JS code provided..

Comment: I have tried the above code I showed image successfully but not hide the text

Comment: @TylerRoper I will improve my question more thanks for your feedback

Comment: @Wimanicesir I have not tried any js code

Comment: _"I want when a user clicks"_ ... for a click event you would need javascript.

Comment: @SalmanIqbal, it's maybe possible to do this with CSS only, but you will have to be a master at it and write a lot. With JS you can put click events on everything you want and easily get the word you clicked on. Do you have any experience with JS?

Comment: @Wimanicesir how do you write click events in css?

Comment: @zgood You could make all words <a> elements and do something when that word is active (aka on click). He actually already did it this way (look at the code). However this is a very annoying job to do this for ALL words. EDIT: in his code he did it when the div was active, so he wasn't going to get there though

Comment: @zgood Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/t845dw9a/ , or you can use `:active` if it's for mouse-hold instead of toggle.

Comment: @Wimanicesir ok I see. thanks for the info! just seems more intuitive to do it in javascript

Comment: @Wimanicesir yes I have experience with js but when using js then the text is moved up and down

Comment: @zgood Yeah, I would strongly advise to use JS instead of CSS :) Like you said, it's way more intuitive!

Comment: When using js the text is moved up and down? This seems like a problem we can solve and not a problem that is connected to JS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the CSS necessary to hide your text. I added below code to hide the text.

```
#story_div:active .pic {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Please check below answer.

**Snippet:**

```css
.pic {
  position: relative;
}

.pic:before {
  content: '';
  /* center */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* scale */
  background-size: 200px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  /* hide */
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 1.5s ease, opacity 1.5s ease;
}

#story_div:active .pic:before {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

#story_div:active .pic {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.pic.horse:before {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.jpeg?text=image');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-size: 300px 200px;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="story_div" class="member-detail-wrap" style="height:500px">
  <div class="sqs-block-content">
    <p id="story">

      <span class="pic horse"> A small horse came to the farm, Sam wanted to play with the </span> horse <span class='pic farm'> but the horse was scared of sam.</span>

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```